# Can a Google Maps Android application run on an emulator?

Tags: google-maps, android-emulator, xamarin, device

I am using Xamarin and have tried many Google Map examples. The map is not displaying on any of the emulators.

My question is this: Can a Google Map be displayed on an emulator, or can it only be displayed on a real device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Google Maps in an emulator because it works only in a real device, you have the option to debug directly in a mobile or tablet to show it, or paste your apk and install it later in order to test it.

I guess this is your answer.

Bye

Comment: Is there anyway to test a Google Maps app in the trial version of Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Maps v2, you are better off using a device than the emulator.

That said, you can use the emulator. Google Maps is only supported on emulators that are running an AVD that is running the most recent Google API. See [comment 29 in bug 57880](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57880#c29).